# We need an accounting Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion

What do you guys think about an accounting Stack Exchange site?

Because the answer is yeah we do. It would be the sexiest thing out there in the Stack Exchange space.

Comment: "sexiest thing"? You are obviously in the wrong place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's already an [Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting) for that. If you want to support that initiative, follow the proposal on Area 51 and participate in the definition of the accounting site.

Comment: And now the proposal has died, so perhaps the world has decided we don't need on after all. It's a funny thing, accounting; the accountants I know ask *other accountants they know* when they aren't sure, rather than the internets